# Python- IF Else statement and return

Tags: python, if-statement, return-value

I'm trying to write a code to let user input a letter and return the digit like our phone keypad. My working is:

```
phone_letters = [" ", "", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQRS", "TUV", "WXYZ"]


def let_to_num():

    letter =input("Enter: ")
    key = 0
    while key < 10:

        if letter.upper() in phone_letters[key]:
            return key
        else:
            return "Not found"

print(let_to_num())
```

However it doesn't work and the correct answer should be:

```
while key < 10:

        if letter.upper() in phone_letters[key]:
            return key
        else:
            key += 1
return "Not found"
```

What i understand is "IF" input not in phone_letter, then we jump to else and return "Not found". "IF" input can find in phone_letter then return "key" and end.

I don't understand why the (return "Not found") put inside the else statement will return  "Not found" for every input?  And what is the function for "key += 1"

Comment: `key+=1` has the same effect as `key = key + 1`.  does the rest of the code make more sense now?

Comment: `return "Not found"` will exit your function immediately. `key` is not raised by one, there is only the validation if `letter.upper()` is in `phone_letters[0]` and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea here is to iterate the `while` from key = 0 to key = 9 (which are the indexes of your `phone_letters` list). In the if block, you check the condition if the entered `letter` is one of the letters of the current iteration of `key`. 

For instance, the user enters letter 'P', the while loop begins -

1. key = 0, phone_letters[key] = " ", condition is False. *Now the value of key must be incremented in order to check the next index of phone_letters. Your code does not do that, instead goes to the else block which returns Not Found in the very first block*
2. key = 1, phone_letters[key] = "", condition is False.
   ...
3. key = 7, phone_letters[key] = "PQRS", condition is True.

Only if the user enters a character that is not present in *any* of your indexes of phone_letters, should the result be Not Found.

Hope that makes it clear!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is due to you setting the value of `key` to 0. This is impacting your `if` statement;

`if letter.upper() in phone_letters[key]:`

This is stating, `in phone_letters[0]:` which is `" "` therefore your check of a letter never returns `true` as it is not in `" "`.

The below code addresses these issues, check out the bottom for links to learn and comments for code function, happy learning!

```
phone_letters = [" ", "", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQRS", "TUV", "WXYZ"]


def let_to_num():

    letter =input("Enter: ")

    while letter.isalpha(): # Only runs if the input is a alphabetical char

        # index of the item in list, if the letter is found within the value
        # of the list item. This loops over every element in the list.
        number = [idx for idx, value in enumerate(phone_letters) if letter.upper() in value]

        return number[0] if number else 'Not Found'

print(let_to_num())
```

Read up on list comprehension here; [List Comprehension in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: If you are going to comprehension: `to_number = {letter: i for i, letters in enumerate(phone_letters) for letter in letters}` and then `number = to_number.get(letter.upper(), 'Not Found')`

Comment: @StephenRauch Updated code with similar concept. Also resolved issue if error thrown if no match.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below,

```
def let_to_num():
    letter = input("Enter: ")
    for i in range(len(phone_letters)):
        if letter.upper() in phone_letters[i]:
            return i
    return 'Not found'
print(let_to_num())
```